# I am trying to created a nested for a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

i am trying to something like this:

```
 <Route path="/cam/cold/general" element={<General />} /> 
        <Route path='/cam/cold/general/substore' element={<jam />} >
          <Route path=':index' >
            <Route path='/order' element={<jam />} />
          </Route>
   </Route>
```

each child is meant to have sub sections

but i keep getting this error

```
router.ts:5 Uncaught Error: Absolute route path "/order" nested under path "/cam/cold/general/substore/:index" is not valid. An absolute child route path must start with the combined path of all its parent routes.
```

Comment: That error is pretty self-explanatory. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: remove `/` from `path="/order"`. So `<Route path='order' element={<jam />} />`

Comment: Also `Jam` is the name of a component and should be capitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

> Uncaught Error: Absolute route path "/order" nested under path
> "/cam/cold/general/substore/:index" is not valid. An absolute child
> route path must start with the combined path of all its parent routes.

The error is informing you that the absolute path `"/order"` can't be nested under `"/cam/cold/general/substore"`. When nesting routes you should use relative routes. The difference between absolute and relative paths is the leading `"/"` character. Absolute paths start with a `"/"`.

## Solution

Remove the leading `"/"` from the nested "order" route.

```
<Route path="/cam/cold/general" element={<General />} /> 
<Route path='/cam/cold/general/substore' element={<Jam />} >
  <Route path=':index'>
    <Route path='order' element={<Jam />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

If you've no other nested routes I suggest to flatten the nesting a bit.

```
<Route path="/cam/cold/general" element={<General />} /> 
<Route path='/cam/cold/general/substore'>
  <Route index element={<Jam />} />
  <Route path=':index/order' element={<Jam />} />
</Route>
```